# "Но когда" в начале предложения. Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, союзы

**Но когда он дошёл до середины пути, Петя свистнул что было силы.**

- По Розенталю, 3) **после союза но** запятая ставится при наличии паузы между союзами и не ставится, если паузы нет: **Но когда** он, опираясь на палку, вышел из штабного автобуса на площадь… Это подпункт к правилу "Постановка запятой **между присоединительным союзом** (в начале предложения, после точки) и следующим за ним подчинительным союзом".
- Получается, что если "но", стоящее в начале предложения, — не присоединительный союз, то надо ставить запятую? А как это определить: присоединительный он или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Союзы ***И, НО, А, ОДНАКО*** в начале предложения считаются присоединительными, и другими они (в начале предложения) просто быть не могут. **У Розенталя пояснение в скобках указывает на то, какие союзы в данной теме он называет присоединительными.**

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140

Постановка запятой между присоединительным союзом (**в начале предложения, после точки**) и следующим за ним подчинительным союзом зависит от значения союза.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Значение союза — имеются в виду просто разные союзы: а, но, и? Ведь значение у них одно — присоединительное.

Comment: Да, все указанные сочинительные союзы в начале предложения являются присоединительными.

Comment: А где можно прочитать про то, что союзы и, но, а, однако в начале предложения считаются только присоединительными? Смущает то, что не каждое предложение, начинающееся с данного союза выражает "добавочные замечания, не предусмотренный первоначальным планом высказывания" (дик.академ) И в поэзии (когда каждая строка с союза "и" начинается), и в прозе множество примеров, когда предложение, начинающееся с союза "и", например, просто продолжает ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНО развивать мысль предыдущего предложения. Хотелось бы какой-то конкретный источник, попространнее: мало замечания в скобках у Розенталя.

Comment: Существует определенная классификация союзов, например: http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=101bbf0d-2055-48e4-94bd-38eefe4661f9  Мы видим, что союзы И, А, НО относятся к сочинительным союзам, но в то же время эти союзы могут выступать в роли присоединительных (тогда в предложении важно определить их функцию). Но союзы соединяют  или присоединяют части предложения, поэтому они обычно находятся в его середине. А вот если они стоят в начале предложения, то они присоединяют новое предложение к предыдущему тексту, отсюда и следует такое название (новое предложение развивает предыдущую мысль).